# Java append text and save file continously

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter, watchservice

I would like to generate line of words continously and append to a text file. As I am using WatchService, I would want to get the line appended immediately. WatchService require me to do a "Save" before it detect the modification to the file and react accordingly. Is there a way to "Save" after each line is appended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flush()` method of your `Writer` after you write the text to you file.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that with `save` you mean `write to disk`, then I would suggest that you use the [flush](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush()) method of BufferedWriter.